# Print all entries in file after (and including) a specific time

Tags: sed, solaris, date

This is my date format in my file: `[1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT]`.

I want to print all entries marked with timestamps from this moment onward to the end of the file. How can I do this using `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to only print the date or the entire line containing the date?

To print the entire line, I would use `grep '\[1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT\]' file`, but if you insist on using `sed`, it can be accomplished with `sed -n '/\[1\/24\/21 9:19:20:183 MYT\]/p' file`.

EDIT: Ugly backslashes can be avoided with `grep -F`, as suggested by user freddy in the first comment below.

The `-n` option ensures that lines are only displayed if they are explicitly printed by the `sed` program. The `p` command explicitly prints the line.

To only print the date, `grep` is also the better solution. You just add the `-o` or `--only-matching` option. It should also be possible with `sed`, but requires more skill than I have.

EDIT: OP actually has a different requirement and modified the question. You can give a line range to `sed`. "from the line that contains [1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT] to the end" is written as `/\[1\/24\/21 9:19:20:183 MYT\]/,$`. The dollar sign indicates the last line. So:

```
sed -n '/\[1\/24\/21 9:19:20:183 MYT\]/,$p' file
```

Comment: i got this error "grep: illegal option -- F" after i use in solaris 11.

Comment: If the Solaris version of grep doesn't have the -F option, use backslashes to remove the special meaning of [ and ]. You could also use the manual page to find out if Solaris grep has an alternative.

Comment: Solaris seems to have two grep versions. From the manual (not sure if Solaris 11) at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/grep-1.html: "The options -E and -F affect the way /usr/xpg4/bin/grep interprets pattern_list".

Comment: @berndbausch `/usr/bin/grep' on Solaris systems is the legacy Solaris `grep` that's pre-POSIX. Solaris has quite a significant forward-compatibility guarantee going back over two decades, so legacy utilities with unique behaviors are kept around - Solaris `awk` is almost legendary (or is that infamous?) in that regard.  `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` is the POSIX-compliant `grep`. And Solaris 11 probably has `ggrep`, which would be GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be `sed`, the following `awk` program would work:

```
awk -v start="[1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT]" 'index($0,start)==1{f=1} f' file
```

This will parse the file until it finds a line starting with the string as specified in the `start` variable. Once found, it sets a flag `f` to 1. Lines are only printed if this flag is set.

This assumes a strict time ordering of entries, i.e. you cannot have "earlier" timestamps occuring after the line with the `start` timestamp. Although improbable, this is possible in case of buffered logging.

Comment: Hi I got below error when i run the awk command 
awk:syntax error near line 1
awk:bailing out near line 1

Comment: @DastageerUmar Hmmm, I tested it with `gawk`, `nawk` and `mawk` on a Linux system and it worked in all cases. Can you post which `awk` version you have?